# node.js won't end TCP connection due to browser crash?

Tags: flash, node.js, tcp

I connect to nodejs server with flash client in browser's window. When borwser is normally closed socket conection is ended, when i end browser's process in task manager connection won't end. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't kill NodeJS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879801/cant-kill-nodejs-app)